Why the time obtained from AudioTimestamp() is always 6ms earlier than the time obtained from SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()?
I'm working on recording Android phone audio and its timestamp. The sampling rate is 11025 Hz and 16 bits.
I read the timestamp right after audioRecord.read() by both SystemClock and AudioTimestamp(). Then I calculated the difference obtained from these two methods, and I found that the time obtained from AudioTimestamp() was always 6 ms earlier than the time obtained from SystemClock.
Why is audioTimeRec 6ms earlier than audioTimeSys_after?
My code is as follow:
audioRecord.read(sData,0,bufferSizeInBytes);
audioTimeSys_after = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos();
stopTs = new AudioTimestamp(); 
int status = audioRecord.getTimestamp(stopTs,TIMEBASE_BOOTTIME);
if (status == audioRecord.SUCCESS) {
  audioTimeRec = stopTs.nanoTime ;
  long time_Diff = audioTimeSys_after-audioTimeRec;
  Log.i("TAG","diff: "+ time_Diff);} 
else {
  Log.e(TAG, "audioRecord.getTimestamp failed with status: " + status);
}

